# Does water vapor affect humidity? Or only when it condensed?

Tags: condensed-matter, water, states-of-matter

The fact says that water vapor is invisible and absolutely in a gaseous state. Does this state of water actually vary the humidity?

Answer (score 3):

the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity)  of humidity states:

> Humidity is the amount of water vapor in the air. Water vapor is the
>   gaseous state of water and is invisible.